# Error for compiling for board Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, hc-sr04

I am new to Arduino and just got this error after writing this code:The error message is pasted after the code. I am kindly requesting for assistance so that someone can help me understand why it isn't compiling. I even changed the board to mega at the tools section but still get the same error

```cpp
    #include <Tone.h>

int ledred1 = 2;
int ledgreen1 = 3;
int ledorange1 = 4;
int ledred2 = 5;
int ledgreen2 = 6;
int ledorange2 = 7;
int ledred3 = 8;
int ledgreen3 = 9;
int ledorange3 = 10;

int sound = 250;

int trigPin1 = 11;
int echoPin1 = 12;

int trigPin2 = 13;
int echoPin2 = 14;

int trigPin3 = 15;
int echoPin3 = 16;

#define buzzer1 17
#define buzzer2 18
#define buzzer3 19

Tone tone1;
Tone tone2;
Tone tone3;

long distance1=0; 
long distance2=0;
long distance3=0; 

long t1=-10000;
long t2=-10000;
long t3=-10000;

void checkDistance(long distance, Tone toneobj, int frequency, long *timer);

long measure(int trigger, int echo);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
 
  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
 
  pinMode(trigPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin3, INPUT);

  tone1.begin(buzzer1);
  tone2.begin(buzzer2);
  tone3.begin(buzzer3);
 
  pinMode(ledred1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledred2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledgreen1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledgreen2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledred3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledgreen3, OUTPUT);
}
void firstsensor(){ // This function is for first sensor. 
  int duration1, distance1;
  digitalWrite (trigPin1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds (10);
  digitalWrite (trigPin1, LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn (echoPin1, HIGH);
  distance1 = (duration1/2) / 29.1;

      Serial.print("1st Sensor: ");
      Serial.print(distance1); 
      Serial.print("cm    ");

  if (distance1 <=200&& distance1>=100) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=250;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
     }   


  if (distance1 <100&& distance1>=50) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=275;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
      }   
        if (distance1 <50&& distance1>=0) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=300;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
      } 
      if(distance1>200 || distance1<0){
    Serial.println("Out of Range");
    noTone(buzzer1);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print(distance1);
    Serial.println("cm");
    tone(buzzer1,sound);

  }  
}
void secondsensor(){ // This function is for second sensor.
    int duration2, distance2;
    digitalWrite (trigPin2, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds (10);
    digitalWrite (trigPin2, LOW);
    duration2 = pulseIn (echoPin2, HIGH);
    distance2 = (duration2/2) / 29.1;
 
      Serial.print("2nd Sensor: ");
      Serial.print(distance2); 
      Serial.print("cm    ");
  
     if (distance2 <=200&& distance2>=100) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=250;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
     }   


  if (distance2 <100&& distance2>=50) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=275;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
      }   
        if (distance2 <50&& distance2>=0) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=300;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
      } 
      if(distance2>200 || distance2<0){
    Serial.println("Out of Range");
    noTone(buzzer2);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print(distance2);
    Serial.println("cm");
    tone(buzzer2,sound);

  }  
}
void thirdsensor(){ // This function is for third sensor.
    int duration3, distance3;
    digitalWrite (trigPin3, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds (10);
    digitalWrite (trigPin3, LOW);
    duration3 = pulseIn (echoPin3, HIGH);
    distance3 = (duration3/2) / 29.1;

      Serial.print("3rd Sensor: ");  
      Serial.print(distance3); 
      Serial.print("cm");
  
     if (distance3 <=200&& distance3>=100) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, HIGH);
    
    sound=250;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
     }   


  if (distance3 <100&& distance3>=50) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=275;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
      }   
        if (distance1 <50&& distance1>=0) {  // Change the number for long or short distances.
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
    
    sound=300;

  } else {
    digitalWrite (ledred1, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange1,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange2,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen2, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledred3, LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledorange3,LOW);
    digitalWrite (ledgreen3, LOW);
      } 
      if(distance3>200 || distance3<0){
    Serial.println("Out of Range");
    noTone(buzzer3);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print(distance3);
    Serial.println("cm");
    tone(buzzer3,sound);

  }  
}

void loop() {
Serial.println("\n");
firstsensor();
secondsensor();
thirdsensor();
delay(100);
}
```

This is the error message:
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"

```
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer0_pin_port'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer0_pin_mask'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer1_pin_port'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer1_pin_mask'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer2_pin_port'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer2_pin_mask'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer0_toggle_count'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer1_toggle_count'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer2_toggle_count'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_7'
libraries/Tone-1.0.0/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the Tone library and you use the `tone()` function from core. They are in conflict.

Use `tone1.tone()` or remove the Tone library and use the `tone()` function.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the tone library and used the tone () function by itself and it worked